# Jersey on was 6.1 : Wrong class definition loaded from WAS plugin directory

Tags: java, jersey, classloader, jax-rs, websphere-6.1

Trying to test a jax rs Jersey application on WAS 6.1, I'm facing the following issue : Jersey needs asm 3.1, especially for the ClassReader class, but an uncompatible version of this class is loaded from WAS plugins directory.

the wrong class definition is loaded from :
file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP70/runtimes/base_v61/plugins/com.ibm.wsfp.main_6.1.0.jar

If I run my application as it, I get a noSuchMethodError :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:     org/objectweb/asm/ClassReader.accept(Lorg/objectweb/asm/ClassVisitor;I)V
    at  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.config.AnnotatedClassScanner.analyzeClassFile(AnnotatedClassScanner.java:322)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.config.AnnotatedClassScanner.indexDir(AnnotatedClassScanner.java:271)
```

....

If I remove this jar from the plugins directory, my asm jar in 3.1 version is picked up and everything is fine.

So here is my question : **what is the good way of dealing with this kind of situation ?** Isn't there a way to tell the server to pick up my jar instead of its jar when I givi it to him ?

Complete problem description [here](http://mathieuhicauber-java.blogspot.fr/2012/12/jax-rs-jersey-on-was-61-asm-classreader.html).

Thank you,

Mathieu.

Comment: Ok answering part of my question : looks like there is a classloader setting PARENT_FIRST / PARENT_LAST that should do the trick. Gonna dig this way : http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27010133&aid=1

Comment: Well the PARENT_FIRST / PARENT_LAST option doesn't solve anything, because its not a server jar that's loaded, but a RAD jar...